# How compare determinate of two matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

$A = [C , j]$ and $B= [C,i]$ two square  matrix such that i and j is a vector. 
i and j have one element of none zero.
what we say about determinate two matrix $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I don't understand the conditions on A, B, C, i, and j.  Can you give an example?

Comment: $A=\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1& 0 & 0\\ 1 &  1 & 0\end{matrix}$ and $B=\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1& 0 & 1\\ 1 &  1 & 0\end{matrix}$ then $j=\begin{matrix}
1 \\
 0\\  0\end{matrix}$ and$i=\begin{matrix}
0 \\
 1\\  0\end{matrix}$

Comment: Aha. So would expansion by cofactors down that right-hand column help?

Comment: I dont know about the  $C$ what use a cofactor ?

Comment: Make sure you understand what the question is asking.  You aren't being asked to compute any determinants at all.  You're being asked about the relationship between two determinants.  Each determinant probably depends on what $C$ is.  But if they were (for instance) equal, you would look for a way to show it in general.  Why don't you take the determinants of the $A$ and $B$ you gave three comments up?